# Lambda as Parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, lambda, filtering

I want to create a method which allows passing a lambda expression as parameter . For example

```
List<T> Select<T>(Predicate<T> criteria)
{
     ...
}
```

The idea is that the fields and values that have happened in the expression can be recovered within this method.

An example of usage could be:

```
List<Contact> list = Select<Contact>(c => c.Id == 1);
```

How do I get the fields and values of the expression

like this

```
string field = something here that you retrieve in this case Id
object value = something here make retrieve id here.
```

Sorry for the English, my native language is Spanish. Thank you and greetings.

Comment: The answer to your question is going to be language-dependent.  You really should tell us what language you are using and add a tag for it.

Answer (score 3):

An example of a `CustomSelect` with some comments

```
public class LinqAsParameter
{
    public class Dummy
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var dummies = new List<Dummy>
        {
            new Dummy { Name = "Jon", Age = 30 },
            new Dummy { Name = "Will", Age = 27 },
        };

        // Calling the custom select method
        IEnumerable<int> ages = dummies.CustomSelect(o => o.Age);
    }
}

// extension class
public static class IEnumerableExtenderLinqAsParameter
{
    // extension method
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> CustomSelect<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> e
      , Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> exp)
    {
        // from the MemberExpression you can get the Member name
        var memberExpression = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        var field = memberExpression.Member.Name; // name
        var compiledExp = exp.Compile(); // compiling the exp to execute
                                         // and retrieve the resulting value

        // run the list an get the value for each item
        foreach (TSource item in e)
        {
            yield return compiledExp(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You might find Jon Skeet's post useful: [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 3 - "Select"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-3-quot-select-quot-and-a-rename.aspx)

Some references from MSDN:

- [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)
- [Func<T, TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a lambda expression as a parameter, you should have the type of argument be either an `Expression<Func<T,TResult>>` or `Func<T,TResult>` depending on whether you expect the expression to be translated to SQL or not.  For example,

```
public List<T> Select<T>( Expression<Func<T,bool>> selector )
{
      return db.GetTable<T>().Where( selector );
}
```

Note, that there isn't necessarily a need to evaluate or inspect the expression directly if you are simply going to use it in a context where the expression type is required.